# php not fetching image location from database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In the process of changing few methods soon to be deprecated in php functions/methods and running into a little trouble.

This code has worked when I used mysql_query

```
function user_id_from_email($email)
{
    $email = sanitize($email);
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'"), 0, 'user_id');   
}

function login($email, $passwd)
{
    $user_id = user_id_from_email($email);
    
    $email = sanitize($email);
    $passwd = sha1($passwd);
    
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `passwd` = '$passwd'"), 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;
    
}
```

Here is the re-written code

```
function user_id_from_email($email)
{
    $email = sanitize($email);
    $db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1','admin','sompass','login');
        if($db->connect_errno){
            $connect_error = 'Sorry, we are experiencing connection problems.'; 
            die ($connect_error);
        }
    $query = "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'";
    if($result = mysqli_query($db, $query)){
        while ($email = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            return $email;
        }
    }
}

function login($email, $passwd)
{
    $user_id = user_id_from_email($email);
    
    $email = sanitize($email);
    $passwd = sha1($passwd);
    
    $db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1','admin','sompass','login');
        if($db->connect_errno){
            $connect_error = 'Sorry, we are experiencing connection problems.'; 
            die ($connect_error);
        }
    $query = "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `passwd` = '$passwd'";
    if($result = mysqli_query($db, $query)){
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($email, $passwd)){
            return $data;
        }
    }
}
```

it is obvious that I'm having trouble converting the queries properly and somehow unable to find the right syntax of maintaining the methods' user_id property when i return my result.  Also please let me forewarn that I would appear inexperienced as you analyze the code because I'm :).  Just a heads up.  with the modified methods I don't get any error message and I have ---ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);--- at the top of my init file.  the problem i'm having is that the image now does not upload or its path is no longer directed properly to its location.  Thank you in Advance.

references I used https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here

```
 while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($email, $passwd)){
        return $data;
    }
```

You need to pass the $result to mysqli_fetch_array - you should have gotten an error. Also I would advise you to get used to using the object oriented style calls, and to remove the while loops. like...

```
$query = "SELECT `user_id` 
              FROM `users`
               WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `passwd` = '$passwd'";
$result = $db->query($query);
return $result->num_rows > 0 ? $user_id : false;
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, however, image is not displayed.  I had indicated to have an attribute such as alt="user's profile image" and that is displayed in place of the image.

Comment: Bryan, would you please elaborate on what $result->num_rows > 0 does??  Thank you!  More importantly what is num_rows

Comment: num_rows is just the count of rows returned by the query, if it's 0 that means no results got returned, try running the query through phpmyadmin and see what kind of results you get

Comment: not to mention, you're only asking for the user_id in the query if you're building the image from the id that's one thing, but if you have a column in the db storing the filename that's not going to be in the result set.

Comment: also you're returning the user id in the mysql version and a result set in the mysqli version.

Comment: what I tried to replicate in mysqli version is the same thing I got with mysql. so Yes i want to return the user id.  I will try to run the query .  thanks again for clarifying the num_rows

Comment: you're not returning the same thing, check the return in my code, i just updated it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46728/discussion-between-user3001162-and-bryan)